# Images go away after minerals = 0

Tags: java

In my program you can place pictures on the applet if you have the required minerals

you start with 400 and each one is 100 minerals so you place 3 and then on the 4th it will delete all the others

```
public int Minerals

    //Pylons
    int xCoord[];
    int yCoord[];
    int numSquare;
    boolean firstPaint;

public void init()
    {   

        Minerals = 400;

        pylon = getImage(getDocumentBase(),"image/pylon.png");
    //pylons
        xCoord = new int[100];
        yCoord = new int[100];
        numSquare = 0;
        firstPaint = true;
}

public void paint(Grapics g)
{


            pylons(g);
}

    public void pylons(Graphics g)
    {
        //Building the pylons
        if(Minerals >= 100)
        {

            for (int k = 0; k < numSquare; k++)
            {
                    g.drawImage(pylon,xCoord[k],yCoord[k],85,85,this);
                    //Makes cursor normal.
                    setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            }

        }

        //Checks if buildPylon is 1 if so it will draw the infoScreen and then set the cursor to pylon
        if(buildPylon == 1)
        {
            g.drawImage(pylon,510,820,100,100,this);
            //Use the custom cursor  
            setCursor(cursor);  
        }
    }

    private void handlePylonPlacement()
    {
        //This takes away 100 minerals and will add 9 population and make buildPylon 0 again
        if(decrementMinerals(100))
            addPopMax(9);
            buildPylon = 0;

    } 

    private boolean decrementMinerals(int amount)
    { 
        //This Is where it takes away the minerals
        if(Minerals - amount >= 0) // prevent situation where you go into negative minerals
        {
             Minerals -= amount;
             return true;
        }
        else
             return false;
    }

    private void addPopMax(int amount)
    {
        //Add the population (9)
        if(popMax + amount <= 72) // restrict addition to pop-max to a sane upper bound
             popMax += amount;
    }


public boolean mouseDown(Event e, int x, int y) {
        //Makes the ints xCoord2 to equal x and same for the other
        xCoord2 = x;
        yCoord2 = y;
        repaint();

        if (numClicks == 10) {//Title screen        
            numClicks++;
            repaint();
        }

    //Checks to see if buildPylon == 1 then builds the pylon if its in the correct place.

    if(buildPylon == 1)
    {
        if(x > 1 && x < 1275 && y > 711 && y < 948) // Checks to see if the person clicked in this area
        {}
        else if(x > 378 && x < 876 && y < 568 && y < 705) // Checks to see if the person clicked in this area
            {}else if (Minerals >= 100) 
            {
            xCoord[numSquare] = x;
            yCoord[numSquare] = y;
            numSquare++;
            handlePylonPlacement(); // call your new handler
            repaint();
             }  
        }



        return true;
    }
```

Instead of it deleting them i want the pylons to stay painted on the screen... any help?

Comment: What does this line if(Minerals >= 100) in pylons() do? Also, where does `buildPylon` get set to 1?

Comment: maybe you forgot it, but `buildPylon` isn't declared anywhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

In `handlePylonPlacement()`, did you mean

```
    private void handlePylonPlacement()
    {
        //This takes away 100 minerals and will add 9 population and make buildPylon 0 again
        if (decrementMinerals(100)) {
            addPopMax(9);
            buildPylon = 0;
        }    
    }
```

?